# Powershell: Using `params` with a Shebang?

Tags: linux, powershell, powershell-core

The `params` keyword lets you add parameters to a Powershell script, like so:

```
param (
  [switch] $UseDefaults = $false
)
```

But it **has to be added to the first line of the script**. A shebang allows us 'nix users to have an easier, more intuitive time starting the script (`./script.ps1` instead of `pwsh script.ts1`) and that can be done by adding this to the start of the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env pwsh
```

However, that also **has to be added to the first line of the script**. Hence, these two features don't seem to be able to work together. Is there a way to use both these features in one script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments and [`using` statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Using) are allowed to precede [`param()` declarations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions#functions-with-parameters), and since a shebang line is technically a comment, it works just fine; for example:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env -S pwsh -noprofile

param(
  [string] $Foo
)

# Print all arguments that were passed
$PSBoundParameters
```

If you save the above to, say, `sample.ps1`, make it executable with `chmod a+x sample.ps1`, then invoke with `./sample.ps1 -Foo bar`, you'll see:

```
Key Value
--- -----
Foo Bar
```

**Important**: As you note, in order for Unix-like platforms to recognize a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line as such, **the file *must not have a BOM***. That is, be sure to save your files as UTF-8 *without a BOM*.<sup>[1]</sup>

Note:

- The use of `/usr/bin/env` to launch `pwsh` assumes that the latter is in one of the directories listed in the `PATH` environment variable.
- `-noprofile` suppresses loading of PowerShell's [profile files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles), which - unfortunately - are loaded *by default*.
- To support passing this extra argument via the shebang line, `-S` must be passed to `env`, for technical reasons (the system passes everything after the executable path as a *single* argument to that executable; `-S` makes `env` split that string into individual arguments).
- There is no technical need to use filename extension `.ps1` in naming your script; in fact, if you want your script to simply function as a general purpose CLI that can be called from *any* shell, you may choose to use *no* filename extension, e.g. to simply name your script `sample`.

  - Conversely, however, if you want to retain the ability to execute your script *in-process* from inside a *PowerShell* session, extension `.ps1` is a must.
  - A caveat is that **calling shebang line-based scripts *from outside PowerShell* or - also from inside PowerShell - a shebang line-based script *without extension `.ps1`* invariably has *syntax and data-type limitations*** (the latter also invariably run in a *child process*), due to the fact that given a shebang line results in invocation via the `-File` parameter of [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the PowerShell (Core) CLI; notably:

    - You can *not* pass *array* arguments (`foo, bar`).
    - You can *not* pass [hashtables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) (`@{ ... }`) or [script blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`)
- Generally, it seems that shebang line-based PowerShell scripts haven't really caught on (yet?), possibly due to a combination of the following factors:

  - The relatively high startup cost of the `pwsh` CLI.
  - The aforementioned syntax and data-type limitations.
  - Various long-standing bugs that haven't been addressed; see [this GitHub query](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues?q=is%3Aissue+in%3Atitle+shebang+is%3Aopen); note that you'll have to click on the `Closed` link to also see still-relevant issues that have simply been closed due to inactivity.

---

###### *Guidance* re if and when to use shebang line-based PowerShell scripts:

- **Do NOT** create shebang line-based scripts...

  - ... if you're primarily calling your scripts from *inside* PowerShell.
  - PowerShell runs `.ps1` scripts *in-process*, which not only means faster execution, but also enables rich (non-serialized) data type-support based on .NET types.
  - PowerShell permits invocation of `.ps1` scripts even without their filename extension, so that you can call `./sample.ps1` as just `./sample`, for instance.
- **DO** create shebang line-based scripts...

  - ... if you primarily use a *different* shell, say `bash`, but need to invoke PowerShell-based code on occasion, and want the convenience of invoking via, say, `./sample.ps1` rather than `pwsh -noprofile sample.ps1`
  - ... if you want to implement a *general-purpose CLI* whose implementation language just so happens to be PowerShell.
  - In either case:

    - The script needs to be designed with the syntax and data-type limitations of a `-File`-based PowerShell CLI invocation in mind.
    - Callers must be aware of PowerShell's [parameter syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Command_Syntax), which generally differs from that of POSIX (single-letter option names such as `-f`) and GNU utilities (with multi-letter option names requiring `--`, e.g. `--color`).

      - That said, even though PowerShell-idiomatically parameters are multi-letter but only require `-` (e.g. `-Path`) in `-File`-based invocations (only), which includes shebang line-based invocations, `--` is accepted too (e.g, `--Path`).
      - However, an important difference is that in PowerShell `-?` rather than `--h` or `--help` must be used to invoke command-line help.

---

<sup>[1] It is only *Windows PowerShell*, the legacy, Windows-only edition of PowerShell that requires a BOM in order to recognize a UTF-8 file as such.</sup>

Comment: Thanks so much for your _very_ thorough answer! I was very confused that I still couldn't get it working with `param`, but I eventually figured out that the file had a BOM at the start. After removing that, the shebang works.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @Jansky; my pleasure. Good point about the BOM - I've added a caveat to the answer.